# UWP Navigation with Frames

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

In my MainPage.xaml I created a `SplitView`. I am using the `SplitView` pane to navigate between my pages. Instead of open new pages, I fill the `SplitView` content with a frame of the page.

I have an active frame called `ProjectsPage`. In this frame I got user controls for each project. Now I want to click on a user control and load a new frame/page called `ProjectDetailsPage`.

I can't navigate from a user control with:

```
ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(ProjectDetailsPage), project);
```

How can I load this new frame?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that `UserControls` are not `Frames`  and neither are they made such that they would be used as one. The best part, navigation only takes place on `Frames`.

In your case scenario,  in simple terms, I have a button on my user control and when I click it, I want to navigate frames to a different `page`. If this is your query, then there are three ways you can go by it:

1. Go up the `visualtree` untill you find a frame and then use that to navigate it. I've only read about such an approach, I haven't tried it either. I personally don't like going up the `visualtree`.
2. You create a static/singleton instance of the navigating frame on your `MainPage` or `ProjectsPage` and  then simply call it from your `usercontrol` and then use it for navigation. Issue with this approach, since you're navigating directly out of the user control here, you won't be able to perform any operations on the ProjectsPage (like resetting defaults and blah blah if you have your `NavigationCache` enabled) before navigating, but as a work around you can put that up in your OnNavigatingFrom override.
3. **Recommended:** This is what I do for a quick solution, I use events, delegates. I write up a quick event in my user control code behind (e.g. `public event Action<MyClass> RequestViewChange;`).

And in the `ProjectsPage` you can subscribe to this event of the `userControl` and when the button is pressed on the user control simple fire up the event and let the `ProjectsPage` listen to it and act accordingly.

I use `Action<T>` as a delegate because I can send in as many event args as possible without defining the content.

I know it's a little unconventional approach but it works like a charm. And very less hassle as compared to going up the visual tree. Feel free to use the comments section.